# Entity relationship

Tags: database

I have started develping database for machineries performance mgt system
Facts:
1.A machine(platNo,model,name) can work on several cane fields(fieldNo,fieldNo)
  - machine vs field
2.Many machineries can work on a cane field 
3.A machine can do tasks for many userDept(deptId,deptName)
4.A userDept demands several machines for its activity{A task can be done on several     cane fields; plowing,land shaping,etc can be done on field 1, 2, 3...- task vs field,
Many tasks can be done on a field; on field 1 , plowing ,harrowing,... can be done
- task vs field?/?}
5.A machine can do for many userDept; lpcd(using its machine) can do the same type of work (e.g.: plowing) for plantation, rehabilitation and expansion projects.
  - task vs userDept
6.Much type of tasks can be done for a userDept; plowing, harrowing,... can be done for plantation-  task vs user
7.A machine works in three shifts(1 -to- 3)

Problem : please help me in designing the ER!!
Thanks,
Dejene

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume platNo can be used as a unique identifier for a machine. There are quite a few possibilities depending on rules that you have left ambiguous - e.g. some of the following relations may not be required or may need to be modified:

MACHINE (platNo, model, name) - *represents each machine*

FIELD (fieldNo) - *represents each cane field*

TASK (taskId, taskName) - *represents the various tasks (e.g. plowing, harrowing) that can be done by any machine*

USERDEPT (deptId, deptName) - *represents each department*

PROJECT (projId, projName, deptId) - *represents each project for each department (e.g. plantation, rehabilitation, expansion)*

SHIFT (shiftNo) - *represents the shifts that any machine might be assigned to*

MACHINE_FIELD (platNo, fieldNo) - *represents the fact that a particular machine can work on a particular cane field*

MACHINE_TASK (platNo, taskId) - *represents the fact that a particular machine can perform a particular task*

PROJECT_REQUIREMENT (projId, taskId) - *represents the fact that a particular project (for a particular department) requires a particular task*

MACHINE_ASSIGNMENT (projId, taskId, shiftNo, platNo) - *represents the fact that a particular machine has been assigned to perform a particular task on a given shift*